# How to Update GridView by changing SelectCommand string in SqlDataSource

Tags: .net, mysql, gridview, sqldatasource, mysql-connector

OK - I think this should be simple/basic but I looked through many posts with similar issues but it is still not clear how to do this.

Basic setup is as follows - I have a TextBox called "product" on the page which posts back on text change.

In page load I do the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   prods.SelectCommand = "SELECT id, pID, pName FROM prods WHERE (pID LIKE '%" + product.Text + "%')";
   prodsTable.DataBind();
}
```

The above does not update the table using the new SelectCommand value. From some other posts - I think this may have to do with Page loading event sequence and maybe table binding does not happen?

BTW, I also tried to do this using parameters (code below) - that does not work either. Maybe there is a simple fix to that (compared to programmatically changing the above to work?)

Thanks in advance - I would like to get it working either way (Programmatically or parametrically).

Full code is below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="product" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="prods" AllowPaging="True" 
     AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
     <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="pID" HeaderText="Product ID" ReadOnly="True" 
               SortExpression="pID" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="pName" HeaderText="Product Name" 
                SortExpression="pName" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" ID="prods" runat="server" 
     CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" ConnectionString="<%$ mystring %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT id, pID, pName FROM prods WHERE (pID LIKE '%@productFilter%')">
     <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="product" DefaultValue="" 
               Name="productFilter" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Is your first line of code supposed to be "prodsTable.SelectCommand"? If not, what is prods?

Comment: Hi Malanie - prods is SqlDataSource that is bound to prodsTable which is GridView table.

Comment: Please post all your code.

Comment: Added full code -- please help; I need to get this working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `SelectCommand="SELECT id, pID, pName FROM prods WHERE pID LIKE '%' + @productFilter + '%'"`

Comment: Hi Yuriy - thanks for response. Do you mean to add the above in C# file or in .aspx file? - the reason I ask is because I thought using + to concatenate string would work only in C# file and reference to parameter @productFilter would only work in .aspx file?

Comment: I tried the following in .aspx file but it did not work: SelectCommand="SELECT id, pID, pName FROM prods WHERE pID LIKE '%' @productFilter '%'"